# What is the best way to merge development database with production?

Tags: wordpress

We develop WordPress websites and we have returning customers who request revisions to their website that require us to develop in a development environment before publishing to production (live). The challenge has always been how to merge two WordPress databases that are out of sync but have mutually new content that must be retained.

This content ranges from Pages, Posts and Comments to Plugin settings and other subtle information. So we export both databases and use FileMerge, for Mac, to display the differences and manually merge them. This would be fine if the WordPress databases didn't contain so much meta information that is, otherwise, human unreadable (examples below).

My question is whether or not someone out there has a recommendation on how to solve this problem? Essentially if we could just omit the items below (assuming that's safe to do?) then we would be perfectly happy continuing to use FileMerge. But with those items it makes it feel like we're decrypting the worlds longest password.

FYI WP Migrate DB (including Pro) is not capable of this. We spoke with the authors.

Thanks.

The following is a list of database records that I think could be omitted without causing any conflicts in the database.
 - _transient_random_seed
 - active_plugins "a" value (which I believe represents the number of active Plugins)
 - _site_transienty_timeout_browser
 - recently_edited
 - db_version
 - cron
 - _transient_timeout_feed_mod
 - _transient_feed_mode
 - rewrite_rules
 - Plugin Versions
 - _edit_locks

Comment: Not a direct answer, but why not just password-protect the 'pre-production' posts, or leave them in draft and ask the client to log in to see them?

Comment: I don't see how that would be a solution in any capacity, but thank you for taking the time to try to help anyway.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Duplicate the posts that need revision & hide them from the public, for only the client to see & approve. Different story with widgets, of course.

Comment: Sure; I mentioned in the second paragraph that the issue is not acute to Posts.

Comment: Granted. I'd still consider it a solution in *some* capacity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been looking at two potential solutions to this problem, however both have the limitation of requiring php exec() on the development/staging server. So hosts like wpengine (which we're using) won't work with them.

If this isn't a limitation for you then check out https://revisr.io/ or  http://versionpress.net/

Revisr is open source and VersionPress is currently using a paid Early Access Program to support development. Both use git to manage all aspects of Wordpress syncing from the WP-Admin.

Comment: VersionPress is now free & open source on GitHub. Revisr is slightly different and cannot merge databases: https://blog.versionpress.net/2015/01/versionpress-vs-revisr/

Answer (score 3):

Try MySQL Data Compare from Red Gate. I use the MSSQL version myself and its one of my favorite development tools. You can select exactly which tables and even the individual records you want to sync. Now for the bad news it only runs on Windows and it is not cheap.
If I wouldn't be developing on a Windows machine myself I would buy one just for this program.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-data-compare/

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same. The closest I got was [WP Stagecoach](https://wpstagecoach.com/) which is one of the few things out there that actually merges data! The downside is you create a dev site from the the live site - which means you have to do all your changes on there... you can then merge back with the live site (data and files).

It means you can't work locally and have to do it on the Stagecoach servers.

Also, one thing to keep an eye on is [Datahawk](https://datahawk.io/), there's no timeframe of when they will release it but it's from the WP Migrate DB Pro guys... I've been told by the developer it will handle merges, how this turns out though I don't know.